# Using scope = $rootScope.$new() or scope = {} in angluar.js unit testing

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I'm learning angular.js unit testing with jasmine and i found examples for accessing controller's scopes by two ways :

as an empty object like this:

```
var $scope = {}; 
var controller = $controller('CalculatorController', { $scope: $scope });
```

Or with the $rootScope.$new() method like this:

```
inject(function($controller, $rootScope) {
      scope = $rootScope.$new();
      var localInjections = {
        $scope: scope,
      };
      $controller('MainCtrl as main', localInjections);
    });
```

and i wonder what is the difference between these two ways?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should go for `$rootScope.$new()`, as doing so will allow you to test for things such as broadcasts.

Having said that, you should try to avoid using `$scope` in controllers and use the [controllerAs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController) syntax instead. See John Papa's excellent [Angular Style Guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/tree/master/a1#controllers)

Answer (score 0):

The first way only creates the scope as a new object.

The second way creates the scope as a child of the `$rootScope` and by doing so you can inherit from it.

E.g.

```
var parent = $rootScope;
var child = parent.$new();

parent.salutation = "Hello";
expect(child.salutation).toEqual('Hello');

child.salutation = "Welcome";
expect(child.salutation).toEqual('Welcome');
expect(parent.salutation).toEqual('Hello');
```

Plus, and I haven't actually tested this yet, I don't think testing for `$scope.$watches` and `$broadcasts` would work if you used the first way.